# ostream&...what is the '&' here?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

While going over some code I came across the following line of code

```
ostream& out = resp.send();
```

The way I interpreted it was that the resp object has a send method that returns an ostream object called out. What is the purpose of the '&' symbol here? Does it mean that the resp object returns a reference to an object of type ostream?

It will be great to get some clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you pretty much answered your own question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The & creates a reference named 'out' to the ostream object that was returned by reference from resp.send().

Note: We know that it was returned by reference because standard stream objects can not be copied therefore it can not be returned by value.

For example:

```
int x =1;
int& y = x;  //y is a reference to x.             
y=2;
cout<<x; //prints 2
```

[Here](http://www.dig.cs.gc.cuny.edu/manuals/C++/Volume1/TIC2Vone-distribution/html/Chapter11.html#Heading326) is a nice explanation of references in C++ (from Bruce Eckel's book Thinking in C++)

Answer (score 0):

The & symbol is used to declare a reference. It doesn't necessarily mean that resp.send() returns a reference, though you could assume that the 'out' variable will be derived from ostream, and be valid.

Just to throw a spanner in the works, it is also possible that resp.send() could return an entirely different object with an implicit conversion to a reference to ostream.

If you are interested, here is a good summary of the properties of references:
http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ref.html